# Mouse cursor isn't visible - how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, logitech-mouse, mouse-cursor

I have an old Windows 10 computer with a Logitech MX wireless mouse. This morning, when I woke my computer, the mouse cursor had disappeared. Rebooting did not solve the problem. How do I get the mouse cursor back?

Comment: Did you check or replace the mouse battery?

Comment: Can it click things, even if you can't see it?

Comment: @help-info.de The mouse works fine with my work laptop. Just not with my old desktop.

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't try clicking, simply because, with no cursor visible, I can't see where I'm clicking. The mouse works fine with my work laptop, so it seems to be software related.

Comment: Remediation begins with triage.

Comment: Try another mouse, anyway. It could be driver related, USB port issue, etc. *Test.*

Comment: @Tetsujin and DrMoishe hit it on the head.  You need to troubleshoot the problem.  Does a wired mouse work?  Do other things work from that port?  Process of elimination will give you your answer.

Comment: No mouse pointer visible could be a few things. The most common are that your computer does not see any pointing human interface device attached, or that you have a second screen attached but turned off. You will need to start trying things and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: It looks like my mouse cursor problem fixed itself. After leaving my computer turned off for a day, I turned it back on, and the mouse cursor was back. (Which is quite strange, considering the fact that my initial reboot to get the cursor back was a power off and on again, since I don't know the keyboard shortcut to do a restart).